# Is there a generalization for the discrete fourier transform whereby eigenvalues are other roots of unity?

Tags: linear-algebra

The eigenvalues of the discrete fourier transform are $\{1, -1, i, -i\}$ in approximately equal proportions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors

Is there a generalization of this transform where the eigenvalues are other roots of unity?

Answer (score 2):

The [Fractional Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform) (and [see here for details in the non-discrete case](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.64.6449&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

Comment: From what I can understand, the fractional fourier transform is just a power of the usual fourier transform. How could it have more than 4 distinct eigenvalues?